# Log In and Log Out simultaniously when guest recovers old account

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I posted a few answers as guest, then recovered an old account. Trying to log in at the sign up or [log in] link at the bottom of a question page I was presented with the sign up form again (where I already had recovered my account). At the same time the guest account drop-down at the top of the page showed me a log out button. I consider that a bug.

I could just log-out, but I'd rather connect my guest answers to my account. Is that possible? If not, consider this a not too serious feature request.

Comment: You mean you want to [merge two accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/245360)?

Comment: That and the UI Bug, yes. Thank you, so far.